# Enter key clears content of Textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = Keys.Enter Then
        TextBox2.Focus()
    End If

End Sub
```

That above code was my codes for moving to another textbox once the textbox1 has a value Or should I say Once i input a value inside the textbox1 and use enter key it should move to TextBox2 but it happened that when you use enter key, textbox1 value has been cleared. My textbox tool is in MultiLine that's why it always happen.

Comment: You should use a title that describes the problem you have, not one that invites people to downvote your post.

Comment: Your posted code doesn't clear anything.  Problem is somewhere else.  On this website, use a four space indent for code samples.

Comment: [TextBox.AcceptReturns property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.acceptsreturn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) note, being a programmer requires that you make a bit of search by yourself

Comment: why not stick with tab like the rest of the world? That said, try putting in e.Handled = True after the call to Focus.

Comment: I've done it after I posted a question. lol the error occured because of the multiline textbox. Sorry for bothering you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `KeyPress` event try using `KeyDown`, and in the code for `TextBox1_KeyDown` enter the following

```
If e.Keys = Keys.Enter
    TextBox_2.Focus()
    e.Handled = true
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Blackwood for editing my answer. I owe you one.

Comment: I've done it after I posted a question. lol the error occured because of the multiline textbox.

Comment: Good work!You might want to post it as the solution in case anyone else checks this question

Comment: oww, the above code was right. It just gain an error because of the property of the textbox when I setup it as "MultiLine."

Comment: It will be nice if you marked the answer (by clicking the tick mark ) so that the solution could be easily identified by anyone who might stumble upon this question.